# how to get Key_name for fingerprint scanner?

Tags: android

Fingerprint API preview for Android N is found [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) with Sample App [Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/) .As of this writing, createKey() in this method specify key_name,i don't know about key_name,Please anyone tell about key_name

```
    /** Alias for our key in the Android Key Store */
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "my_key";


     public void createKey() {
    // The enrolling flow for fingerprint. This is where you ask the user to set up fingerprint
    // for your flow. Use of keys is necessary if you need to know if the set of
    // enrolled fingerprints has changed.

     try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
        // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder

        mKeyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                        // of the key
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        mKeyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

this my part of code,here  what is KEY_NAME and key_name get from where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run this cmd on your terminal

/home/nn1android01user/Documents/Keystor_alicante/gerber_keystore.jks ->
this is your keystore file path

gerber -> alias name

```
keytool -exportcert -alias gerber -keystore /home/nn1android01user/Documents/Keystor_alicante/gerber_keystore.jks | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```